# How to display record in gridview according to the from date textbox to todate textbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

i have two textboxes 1 button and 1 gridview and 1 button

database structure :

```
ID    NAme      Age     date
1     sumit     24      1-Mar-2011
2     Manish    22      5-Mar-2011
```

what i want to do...

i have to text boxes textbox1 in which user enter from date and in textbox2 user enetr to date and after button clickevent the gridview will display the record between fromdate and to date..

mysql query ..

```
SELECT Ticket_no, journey_date, Travels, route, sel_seat, seat_opt, net_pay, name, mob, book_date, PNR_no FROM a1_ticket WHERE journey_date BETWEEN journey_date1 AND journey_date2 ORDER BY ID DESC


journey_date1 =textbox1
journey_date2 =textbox2
```

whats wrong in this query ?

ERREO : It will notdisplay record according to query ..

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  orderby
```

to

```
 order by
```

not sure if this will fix all your problems, or if that syntax is actually valid.

Comment: ya that is not an issue ... i changes ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

I think in the Query, there may be problem in Converting the Datetime to the format you specified in your table.